# Is there an image annotation app for django?

Tags: django, image, annotations

I was looking for a Django app that would let me select portions of images and 'annotate' them with tags or text.

I guess one approach could be using plugins such as [jquery-image-annotate](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-image-annotate/) and integrate it with my django app (preferably the admin) - but I was wondering whether there's already something that does that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you take a look to https://github.com/opencv/cvat ? it uses Django, but I am not sure if you can plug-and-play as a pluggable, take a look.

> Computer Vision Annotation Tool (CVAT) is a web-based tool which helps to annotate video and images for Computer Vision algorithms. It was inspired by Vatic free, online, interactive video annotation tool. CVAT has many powerful features: interpolation of bounding boxes between key frames, automatic annotation using TensorFlow OD API, shortcuts for most of critical actions, dashboard with a list of annotation tasks, LDAP and basic authorization, etc… It was created for and used by a professional data annotation team. UX and UI were optimized especially for computer vision tasks.